# Python: If statement return ValueError

Tags: python, pandas

I create a if statement with pandas and return error as below:

> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

My code is as below:

```
>>> df_1
    timestamp  open  high   low  close  adjusted_close  volume  \
0  2017-09-01  1.17  1.24  1.16    1.2             1.2   47932   
   dividend_amount  split_coefficient  
0              0.0                1.0  
>>> df_o
   timestamp  open  high   low  close  adjusted_close  volume  \
0  2017-08-31  1.15  1.27  1.06    1.29             1.29   97932   
   dividend_amount  split_coefficient  
0              0.0                1.0  
>>>if df_1['timestamp']!= df_o['timestamp'].tail(1):
....    print "different date"
>>>>Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/vinus/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 892, in __nonzero__
    .format(self.__class__.__name__))
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

How can I avoid the error?
It is cause by `if df_1['timestamp']!= df_o['timestamp'].tail(1):`

Comment: There are always 1 row dataframes? Because `df_1['timestamp']!= df_o['timestamp'].tail(1)` return `Series` - array of `True` with `False`s.

Comment: `df_o['timestamp'].tail(1)` can be multiples rows. `df_1['timestamp']` is one row

Comment: so `tail(1)` can be `tail(3)` ?

Comment: no, your answer should work. I am testing with it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If always one row `DataFrames` convert values to scalars and then compare:

```
if df_1['timestamp'].iat[0] != df_o['timestamp'].iat[0]:
```

---

```
if df_1['timestamp'].values[0] != df_o['timestamp'].values[0]:
```

---

```
if df_1['timestamp'].item() != df_o['timestamp'].item():
```

**Sample**:

```
df_1 = pd.DataFrame({'timestamp':['2017-09-01']})
df_o = pd.DataFrame({'timestamp':['2017-08-31']})

if df_1['timestamp']!= df_o['timestamp'].tail(1):
    print ('not equal')
```

> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

```
print (df_1['timestamp']!= df_o['timestamp'].tail(1))

0    True
Name: timestamp, dtype: bool
```

---

```
print ((df_1['timestamp']!= df_o['timestamp'].tail(1)).values[0])
True
```

---

But if need compare `Series` (column) with scalar get another `True, False` Series and cannot use `if` working with scalars only:

```
df_1 = pd.DataFrame({'timestamp':['2017-09-01']})
df_o = pd.DataFrame({'timestamp':['2017-08-31', '2017-09-01', '2017-06-10', '2017-08-12']})

print (df_o['timestamp'].tail(3) != df_1['timestamp'].iat[0])
1    False
2     True
3     True
Name: timestamp, dtype: bool
```

And for scalars are use 2 methods - [`any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.any.html) for check at least one `True` and [`all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.all.html) for check if all values are `True`s:

```
print ((df_o['timestamp'].tail(3) != df_1['timestamp'].iat[0]).any())
True

print ((df_o['timestamp'].tail(3) != df_1['timestamp'].iat[0]).all())
False
```

Comment: could you explain what is convert to scalars and what is actually wrong with my previous code?

Comment: I think problem is you compare 2 Series - they are one length size, so you think comapring is same as scalars. But comparing `Series` return another Series, (1 length size). And for comapre with `if` need scalar.